# how to make pairs from odd number of people one may be alone?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How Many ways the pairs can be formed from the group of size odd(like 3,5), one may be left alone?

Eg: there are 5 students, so 2 pairs can be formed and one guy left alone...

|Consider (a,b,c,d,e) are 5 distinct person , According to me only 6 ways are possible

```
|  (a,b)  |     (a,c)       |   (a,d)         |      (a,e)        |
___________________________________________________________________
|  (c,d)  |  (b,e)          | (b,c)           |  (b,c)(redundant) |
|  (c,e)  |  (b,d)          | (b,e)(redundant)|  (b,d)(redundant) |
|  (d,e)  | (d,e)(redundant)| (c,e)(redundant)|  (c,d)(redundant) |
__________________________________________________________________
```

Is it correct? what will be the formula for this?

Comment: Why do you mark the ones redundant?  $(a,c),(d,e)$ is never counted.  You seem to be counting the number of pairs you can form, which if you include the first line is $10$.  As you say, that is ${5 \choose 2}=\frac 12\cdot 5 \cdot 4=10$

Comment: thanks for the reply. actually, that was my approach ... i don't think my approach is correct .......  i considered that we don't want to count the formation if the pair is already formed

Comment: @RossMillikan but doing 5C2 will give me the possible ways of formation of a single pair..

Comment: Correct.  That is the count of the pairs you have not marked redundant in your table, including the top line.  None of the entries are redundant and you have found $12$ ways to make the pairing if you require that $a$ be paired.  There are $3$ more where $a$ is the one alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are $n$ people you can choose the first pair in $n \choose 2$ ways, then the next in $n-2 \choose 2$ ways, and so on.  You have made $\frac 12(n-1)$ groups and you could have made the groups in any order, so the number of ways is $${n \choose 2}{n-2 \choose 2}\ldots {2\choose 2}\frac 1{(\frac 12(n-1))!}=\frac{n!}{2^{(\frac 12(n-1))}}\frac 1{(\frac 12(n-1))!}$$
For $n=5$ this evaluates to $15$.  There are $10$ ways to pick the first pair, $3$ ways to pick the second, and you divide by $2$ for the orders to pick the pairs.  There are the twelve cases you list in your table (including the redundant ones) plus three where $a$ is alone.

Comment: so, this formula looks similar to even case .......... Actually, this question was in my mind. so, I don't know the answer ... but still confused...marking as it correct.. thanks

Comment: It should look like the formula in the even case.  If you have an even number $k$ of people and do a pairing, you can just remove the last person and you have a unique pairing of $k-1$ people, so there are the same number.

Comment: thank you so much :) ... understood

Answer (score 0):

You have to count the number of possible configurations
$$
\{*\},\{*,*\},\{*,*\}
$$
You can choose the single element in $5$ ways, then the first pair in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. However, you have to divide by $2!$, because you can permutate the pairs:
$$
5\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2!}=5\cdot6/2=15
$$
There would also be a $\binom{2}{2}$ factor for the last pair, which I omitted.

Similarly for $2n+1$ elements:
$$
(2n+1)\binom{2n}{2}\binom{2n-2}{2}\dotsm\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n!}
$$
Can we do a recursive formula? Yes, if $P_n$ is the number corresponding to $2n+1$ elements, then $P_0=1$ and
$$
\frac{P_{n+1}}{P_n}=\frac{2n+3}{2n+1}\binom{2n+2}{2}\frac{1}{n+1}=2n+3
$$
Indeed,
$$
P_1=3,\quad P_2=(2\cdot1+3)\cdot3=15
$$
and so on.

Since $P_{n+1}=(2(n+1)+1)P_n$, if we set $Q_{2n+1}=P_n$, we have [$Q_k=k!!$](https://oeis.org/A001147) (the [semifactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)), for odd $k$.

Comment: thank you for further elaboration and replying...